# syntax error in awk 'if-else if-else' with multiple operations

Tags: awk, conditional-statements

There's a weird thing with awk conditional statements:

when running awk 'if-else if-else' with a single operation after each condition, it works fine as below:

```
awk 'BEGIN {a=30; \
if (a==10) print "a = 10"; \
else if (a == 20) print "a = 20"; \
else print "a = 30"}'
```

output:
`a = 30`

However, when running awk 'if-else if-else' with multiple operations (properly braced) after 'else if' , syntax error occured:

```
awk 'BEGIN {a=30; \
if (a==10) print "a = 10"; \
else if (a == 20) {print "a = 20"; print "b = 20"}; \
else print "a = 30"}'
```

output:

```
awk: cmd. line:4: else print "a = 30"}
awk: cmd. line:4: ^ syntax error
```

Can anyone tell if this is an awk issue that intrinsically doesn't allow multiple operations in such cases, or if it's just my syntax error that could be corrected?

P.S. I looked through all relevant posts of awk 'if else' syntax error, but none of them is addressing this issue.

Comment: it works as `awk 'BEGIN {a=30; \
if (a==10) print "a = 10"; \
else if (a == 20) {print "a = 20"; print "b = 20"} \
else print "a = 30"}'`. You're are right, and it has nothing to do with multiple operations! I didn't even realize that the semi-colon should be removed between 'else if' and 'else'...I just removed all unnecessary semi-colons.

Comment: None of the line continuations are needed inside a single quoted string.

Comment: Remove semi-colon (`;`) at end of third line after close brace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed semi-colon at end of third line after close brace.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {a=30; \
if (a==10) print "a = 10"; \
else if (a == 20) {print "a = 20"; print "b = 20"} \
else print "a = 30"}'
```

Output: `a = 30`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
awk 'BEGIN {a=30; \
if (a==10){ print "a = 10"}\
else if(a == 20) {print "a = 20"} \
else{ print "a = 30"}}'
```